# Fixed buttons in scrollable menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two buttons at the end of my dropdown menus, apply + clear. Both buttons should take 50% of the full width of the menu before the top-down scroll thingie. However, the menu width is variable based on the text length of the checkbox values. At the beginning of my dropdown menus I have Typeahead box, and also that is not wide for the full width of the variable menu box. Also, the box is fixed at the top, but not neatly and when scrolling down the checkbox values, these values overlap with my Typeahead box. Is it possible to achieve all that? I cannot get it right.

Code in BOOTPLY... [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/nAupRgzzAp#)

```css
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.checkbox :hover {
      background-color:red;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

.div_form :hover {
      background-color:green;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

.btn_clear {
    float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: auto;
 padding: 10px 29px;
 text-align: center;
    background-color:grey
  }
  
.btn_apply {
    float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: auto;
 padding: 10px 17px;
 text-align: center;
    background-color:yellow
    }


.checkbox label, .radio label {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right:30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.div_form {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 bottom: -70px
}

.btn {
 border-radius:0;
 margin-top:5px
}

.dropdown-menu {
 border-radius:0;
 border:5px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    min-width:400px
}

.typeahead {
 width:auto;
 margin-left:10px
}

.typeahead {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    top:-10px
  }
```

Comment: The `background-color` of your typeahead is autoset to `background-color: transparent` when your code is run, that is the reason the values overlap the typeahead.

Comment: For input box, you can use z-index property and for buttons you can use 50% width.. or any other issue you are facing?